# react navigation: navigate outside component | map function

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-navigation

Hello I'm new to RN and I have little problem with my react navigation. I would like to write boxes from an array. Every box has same navigation path. I guess it's problem with navigating outside component but I have no idea how to fix it.

CODE:

```
WriteTeams() {
    return teams_array.map(function(Teams, i){
        return(
        <View key={i}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('TeamDetail')}>
                <Text>{Teams.TeamName}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        );
    });
}
render(){
       <ScrollView>
           <View>
              <View>
                 {this.WriteTeams()}
              </View>
           </View>
       </ScrollView>
    }
}
const teams_array = [
  { TeamName: "Some team"},
  { TeamName: "Some team2"}
]
```

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5UNU.png)

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the navigation object is not being passed into the component as a property.

You will need to pass the navigation object from the render function to the WriteTeams component to make it available in your code.

I have copied and amended your code to help explain

```
WriteTeams(navigation) {
    return teams_array.map(function(Teams, i){
        return(
            <View key={i}>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TeamDetail')}
                >
                    <Text>{Teams.TeamName}</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    });
}
render(){
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                <View>
                    {this.WriteTeams(this.props.navigation)}
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
const teams_array = [
    { TeamName: "Some team" },
    { TeamName: "Some team2" }
]
```